# How to cope with an electrical box set too deep in the wall?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have an electrical box that is set about 1/8" too deep in the wall so when the switchplate is installed the receptable plugs are sunken into the plate and recessed.

How can I position the outlet farther out so that it is flush with the switchplate?

Comment: use spacers ...

Comment: @jsotola What is a spacer?

Comment: something that fills a gap between two objects ... in your case, a 1/8" thick washer

Comment: I know some of the big box stores carry those spaces (plaster rings), in various depths/thicknesses and for single gang and double gang boxes.  You also may need longer screws to go through the ring and into the box, to mount the outlet or switch.  Oh, and please don't use drywall screws for that.

Comment: Can you add that this is [presumably] US, because in the UK the answer would be either  'buy longer pattress screws' or 'this situation cannot arise because of the plate design.'

Answer (score 6):

Usually use an Arlington BE1, but depth and wall material may render other options easier, like a Caddy RLC, RACO Add-a-depth ring, or Gardner Bender GSP-04.

> NEC 314.20 Flush-Mounted Installations. Installations within or behind
> a surface of concrete, tile, gypsum, plaster, or other noncombustible
> material, including boxes employing a flush-type cover or faceplate,
> shall be made so that the front edge of the box, plaster ring,
> extension ring, or listed extender will not be set back of the
> finished surface more than 6 mm (1∕4 in.).
>
> Installations within a surface of wood or other combustible surface
> material, boxes, plaster rings, extension rings, or listed extenders
> shall extend to the finished surface or project therefrom.

Answer (score 4):

Normally the receptacle mounting screws have a flat square nut behind the receptacle mounting threads , this allows you to position the receptacle outward from the box, yours are probably missing and that's why you are asking. Sometimes people remove the mounting screws and lose the flat square nut and don't think about it, till you need it.